# Echoing HTML select value not giving same value set

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I have this html select value that I used with AngularJS in building. Anytime I print the value selected from html in php, I keep getting a different thing. Eg. I selected Computer from the select group and the value="computer", when I echo in php, I get something like this:

> ? string: computer ?

I can't figure what the problem is.
HTML code below

```
<div class="form-group" form-group-sm>
    <label>Faculty/School:</label>
    <select name="faculty" class="form-control" ng-model="tfaculty">
        <option value="Engineering">Faculty of Engineering</option>
        <option value="Medicine">Faculty of Medicine</option>
        <option value="Agriculture">Faculty of Agriculture</option>
        <option value="Bioscience">Faculty of Bioscience</option>
        <option value="Physical Science">Faculty of Physical Science</option>
        <option value="Law">Faculty of Law</option>
        <option value="Mgt Tech">Faculty of Management Sci./Tech.</option>
        <option value="Soc. Science">Faculty of Social Science</option>
        <option value="Health Sci.">Faculty of Health Sci. and Tech.</option>
        <option value="Envt Tech">Faculty of Environmental Sci./Tech.</option>
        <option value="Education">Faculty of Education</option>
        <option value="Arts">Faculty of Arts</option>                                                                  
    </select>
</div>
<!--this section shows to choose department-->
<div class="form-group" form-group-sm>
    <span ng-show="tfaculty == 'Engineering'">
        <label>Department:</label>
        <select name="department" class="form-control" ng-model="tdepartment">
            <option value="Elect Elect Eng">Electrical and Electronics</option>
            <option value="Computer Eng">Computer Engineering</option>
            <option value="Chemical Eng">Chemical Engineering</option>
            <option value="Civil Eng">Civil Engineering</option>
            <option value="Petroleum Eng">Petroleum Engineering</option>
            <option value="Mechanical Eng">Mechanical Engineering</option>
            <option value="Polymer Eng">Polymer and Textile</option>
            <option value="Met Mat Eng">Material and Metallurgical</option>
            <option value="Agric and Bio">Agric and BioResources</option>
            <option value="Mechatronics Eng">Mechatronics Engineering</option>                                                       
        </select>
    </span>
    <span ng-show="tfaculty == 'Medicine'">
        <label>Department:</label>
        <select name="department" class="form-control" ng-model="tdepartment">
            <option value="Surgery">Surgery</option>
            <option value="Anaesthesiology">Anaesthesiology</option>
            <option value="Chemical Pathology">Chemical Pathology</option>
            <option value="Haematology">Haematology</option>
            <option value="Histopathology">Histopathology</option>
            <option value="Medicine">Medicine</option>
            <option value="pthamology">Opthamology</option>
            <option value="Paediatrics">Paediatrics</option>
            <option value="Radiology">Radiology</option>
            <option value="Medical Microbiology">Medical Microbiology</option>
            <option value="Anatomy">Anatomy</option>
            <option value="Physiology">Physiology</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span ng-show="tfaculty == 'Agriculture'">
        <label>Department:</label>
        <select name="department" class="form-control" ng-model="tdepartment">
            <option value="Agric Economics">Agric Economics and Extension</option>
            <option value="Crop Science">Crop Science and Horticulture</option>
            <option value="Animal Science">Animal Science</option>
            <option value="Forestry">Forestry and Widelife</option>
            <option value="Fisheries">Fisheries and Aquaculture</option>
            <option value="Food Science">Food Science and Technology</option>
            <option value="Soil Science">Soil Science and Land Resources</option>
        </select>
    </span>
```

Php code below:

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) { //narrowing d search by department

        $department = $_POST['department'];

        echo $department;}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that POST the data to the server? Are you using AJAX for that or just a regular form POST?

Comment: Also, not an Angular dev, but it looks like `ng-show` adds `display:none` CSS property so is it possible that two options are being submitted? You can use Google Chrome dev tools to see what is actually POSTing. You would use the Network tab. When you submit the form, you should see the URL you POSTed to. Click that and then look at Request Payload.

Comment: I am using a form POST. the POST works fine, but just when I echo the value it posted, it gives me the value but and additional character

Comment: I am using a form POST. the POST works fine, but just when I echo the value it posted, it gives me the value but and additional character   ie   "?string: value ?".....dnt know how the string and the question mark came to be

Comment: Instead of `echo`, try `var_dump($department)` and let me know what that gives you. And are you using a PHP framework or just PHP?

Comment: using just php. will try `var_dump($department)`

Comment: `var_dump($department)` did not work also